# Show partial from another controller or model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Project that `has_many` tasks. The Task has a `_form.html.erb` file that I wanted to show on my `show.html.erb` file from Project.

But everytime I try this, I am getting the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `task'

I am using `<%= render 'tasks/form' %>` to render the partial.

Also, would

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %> 
<%= listing.task.name %> 
<% end %>
```

do the trick to show all listings that's associated with the current page?

Comment: Could you provide the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Please stick with one question per post. Stack Overflow is a Q&A format site, and lumping multiple questions under a single post damages the ability of future readers to find the answers they're looking for.

Comment: At a best guess, I'd say that your `_task` partial is expecting you to pass in an actual task as a local variable... which you can do with something like: `<%= render 'tasks/form', :task => (@task || Task.new) %>` But I'm just guessing (given we don't have a stacktrace or your partial template's code to look at).

Comment: @TarynEast i was about to post the trace, but your code just fixed the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just missing to pass the `task` local to the partial.

This should work:

```
<%= render partial: 'tasks/form', locals: { task: @task } %>
```